# Coverting typescript string literal types to an array of string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have

```
type ImageVerticalSpacing = 'ignoreBottom' | 'ignoreTop' | 'ignoreBoth' 
| 'Default';
```

in typescript and need to pass those strings as an array of strings to a dropdown.
How can I convert type ImageVerticalSpacing to an array of strings?

Answer (score 14):

Building on top of [jcal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45626720/3047190) and reiterating: "You can't convert types in TypeScript to values at runtime. But you can do the reverse: create a runtime object and have TypeScript infer its type." There is a great blog post by @steve-holgado to use const assertions for this purpose: https://steveholgado.com/typescript-types-from-arrays/

With typescript's [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) (TypeScript 3.4+) you can do:

```ts
const animals = ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse'] as const
type Animal = typeof animals[number]

// type Animal = 'cat' | 'dog' | 'mouse'
```

So the question's code would look like:

```ts
const imageVerticalSpacing = ['ignoreBottom', 'ignoreTop', 'ignoreBoth', 'Default'];
type ImageVerticalSpacing = typeof imageVerticalSpacing[number];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't convert types in TypeScript to values at runtime.  But you can do the reverse: create a runtime object and have TypeScript infer its type.

The ideal runtime object for this purpose would be a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple).  Unfortunately, TypeScript doesn't infer tuples that well by itself.  I use a helper function called `tuple()` which returns tuple types.

UPDATE: 2018-12, since TypeScript 3.0 the `tuple()` function can be written like this:

```
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | symbol | 
  object | {} | void | null | undefined;
const tuple = <T extends Narrowable[]>(...args: T)=>args;
```

Using the above helper function, you can do this:

```
const imageVerticalSpacing = tuple('ignoreBottom','ignoreTop','ignoreBoth','Default');

type ImageVerticalSpacing = (typeof imageVerticalSpacing)[number];
```

The `imageVerticalSpacing` object is an array of strings you can use for your dropdown, of type `['ignoreBottom','ignoreTop','ignoreBoth','Default']`.  And the type `ImageVerticalSpacing` is the same `'ignoreBottom' | 'ignoreTop' | 'ignoreBoth' | 'Default'` as you declared.

(See it in action on [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Narrowable%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20boolean%20%7C%20symbol%20%7C%20%0A%20%20object%20%7C%20%7B%7D%20%7C%20void%20%7C%20null%20%7C%20undefined%3B%0Aconst%20tuple%20%3D%20%3CT%20extends%20Narrowable%5B%5D%3E%28...args%3A%20T%29%20%3D%3E%20args%3B%0A%0Aconst%20imageVerticalSpacing%20%3D%20tuple%28%27ignoreBottom%27%2C%27ignoreTop%27%2C%27ignoreBoth%27%2C%27Default%27%29%3B%0Atype%20ImageVerticalSpacing%20%3D%20%28typeof%20imageVerticalSpacing%29%5Bnumber%5D%3B%0A))

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript interfaces or type aliases don't exist at runtime. So you cannot use the values from them at runtime. You can try using an enum:

```
enum ImageVerticalSpacing  {
    ignoreBottom,
    ignoreTop,
    ignoreBoth,
    Default
}

Object.keys(ImageVerticalSpacing).filter(k => isNaN(k as any)) // The filter is to filter out the index keys that TypeScript generates. See the generated JS code
// ["ignoreBottom", "ignoreTop", "ignoreBoth", "Default"]
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20ImageVerticalSpacing%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ignoreBottom%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ignoreTop%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20ignoreBoth%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Default%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AObject.keys(ImageVerticalSpacing).filter(k%20%3D%3E%20isNaN(k%20as%20any)))